# second element to fill remaining vertical space

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a container with fixed height.

The container has 2 paragraphs.

I want the first `p` to have a dynamic height (with min-height and max-height) depending on it's content and the second p to take up the remaining vertical space.

e.g in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ryZvL/): I want the pink p to fill the remaining yellow space, and to shrink accordingly when the first p element grows.

I have seen how to get a div to fill up horizontal space (ie with a `bfc` - block formatting context) but I cant seem to find a css solution for a vertical filler.

If this can't be done with css i'd like to know how to do this with jquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the second pink div like this

```
.two
{
    background-color: pink;
    height: inherit;
}
```

[See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/4jMqx/)

Comment: Doesn't work, the second div gets the same height as the parent, therefore the sum of both div's height is bigger than the parent's height.

Answer (score 1):

With jquery you can do that:
try it:

```
var fillRemaining = $("p.one").parent().height() - $("p.one").height();
$(".p.two").css('height',fillRemaining);
```

done ...
Good luck

Comment: @MichaelAntonius: cache your selectors; your second selector is incorrect. Filtering by `p` is uneccesary, since sizzle does selector matching right to left. `var $one = $('.one'), fillRemaining = $one.parent().height() - $one.height(); $('.two').css('height', fillRemaining)`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the way to do this is with [css tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display).

Setting `height:100%` on the second table-row is what causes it to take up the 'remaining height'

**[Updated fiddle - little content](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ryZvL/13/)**

**[Updated fiddle - more content](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ryZvL/14/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="one">
        text1
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        text2
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wrapper
{
    height:200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: table;
}
.wrapper > div
{
    width: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}
.one
{
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 180px;
    background-color: beige;
    text-align: left;

}
.two
{
    background-color: pink;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

if you are dealing with the `background colors` you can [do this trick](http://jsfiddle.net/ryZvL/3/)

Comment: no i'm not interested in the colors - i just used them to make it easier to explain what i need